# JFrame with custom border not showing controls

Tags: java, swing, jframe, border, paint

I'm trying to make my own custom border, and I have done this through overriding the paint function in the JFrame.  The problem which I have run into, is the fact that paint is being called after the constructor, causing it to paint the window over my controls.  Because of this, my table only appears when I happen to click on where it is in the JFrame.  I was wondering if there is a way to make the paint function happen before my constructor, or if there is a better way to create a custom border.  Here is my code:

```
public class GuiMain extends JFrame {

    int posX=0, posY=0;

    JTable serverList;

    public GuiMain()
    {
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        serverList = new JTable(Variables.servers, Variables.serversHeader);
        add(serverList);

        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
                posX = e.getX();
                posY = e.getY();
            }
        });
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt)
            {
                if(posY <= 20) {
                    setLocation(evt.getXOnScreen()-posX, evt.getYOnScreen()-posY);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(new Color(100, 100, 100));
        g.fillRect(0,  0, Main.width, Main.height);

        g.setColor(new Color(70, 70, 70));
        g.fillRect(0,  0, Main.width, 20);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You know that it is not the safest thing to do, overriding `paint(...)` of a top-level window. What type of "border" are you trying to create? Where is your call to `super.paint(g);`? Myself, I'd create my own class that extended the AbstractBorder class, and then would use that Border on a JPanel that is the JFrame's contentPane.

For example,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FrameEg extends JPanel {
   public static final String FRAME_URL_PATH = "http://th02.deviantart.net/"
         + "fs70/PRE/i/2010/199/1/0/Just_Frames_5_by_ScrapBee.png";
   public static final int INSET_GAP = 120;

   private BufferedImage frameImg;
   private BufferedImage smlFrameImg;

   public FrameEg() {
      try {
         URL frameUrl = new URL(FRAME_URL_PATH);
         frameImg = ImageIO.read(frameUrl);

         final int smlFrameWidth = frameImg.getWidth() / 2;
         final int smlFrameHeight = frameImg.getHeight() / 2;
         smlFrameImg = new BufferedImage(smlFrameWidth, smlFrameHeight,
               BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
         Graphics g = smlFrameImg.getGraphics();
         g.drawImage(frameImg, 0, 0, smlFrameWidth, smlFrameHeight, null);
         g.dispose();

         int top = INSET_GAP;
         int left = top;
         int bottom = top;
         int right = left;
         Insets insets = new Insets(top, left, bottom, right);
         MyBorder myBorder = new MyBorder(frameImg, insets);

         JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(50, 60);
         textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
         textArea.setLineWrap(true);
         for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            textArea.append("Hello world! How is it going? ");
         }
         setLayout(new BorderLayout(1, 1));
         setBackground(Color.black);

         Dimension prefSize = new Dimension(frameImg.getWidth(),
               frameImg.getHeight());
         JPanel centerPanel = new MyPanel(prefSize);
         centerPanel.setBorder(myBorder);
         centerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1, 1));
         centerPanel.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);

         MyPanel rightUpperPanel = new MyPanel(new Dimension(smlFrameWidth,
               smlFrameHeight));
         MyPanel rightLowerPanel = new MyPanel(new Dimension(smlFrameWidth,
               smlFrameHeight));
         top = top / 2;
         left = left / 2;
         bottom = bottom / 2;
         right = right / 2;
         Insets smlInsets = new Insets(top, left, bottom, right);
         rightUpperPanel.setBorder(new MyBorder(smlFrameImg, smlInsets));
         rightUpperPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         rightLowerPanel.setBorder(new MyBorder(smlFrameImg, smlInsets));
         rightLowerPanel.setBackgroundImg(createBackgroundImg(rightLowerPanel
               .getPreferredSize()));

         JTextArea ruTextArea1 = new JTextArea(textArea.getDocument());
         ruTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
         ruTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
         rightUpperPanel.add(new JScrollPane(ruTextArea1), BorderLayout.CENTER);

         JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 1, 1));
         rightPanel.add(rightUpperPanel);
         rightPanel.add(rightLowerPanel);
         rightPanel.setOpaque(false);
         add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private BufferedImage createBackgroundImg(Dimension preferredSize) {
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(preferredSize.width,
            preferredSize.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Point2D center = new Point2D.Float(img.getWidth()/2, img.getHeight()/2); 
      float radius = img.getWidth() / 2;
      float[] dist = {0.0f, 1.0f};
      Color centerColor = new Color(100, 100, 50);
      Color outerColor = new Color(25, 25, 0);
      Color[] colors = {centerColor , outerColor };
      RadialGradientPaint paint = new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, dist, colors);
      Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
      g2.setPaint(paint);
      g2.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
      g2.dispose();

      return img;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      FrameEg mainPanel = new FrameEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameEg");
      frame.setUndecorated(true);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
   private Dimension prefSize;
   private BufferedImage backgroundImg;

   public MyPanel(Dimension prefSize) {
      this.prefSize = prefSize;
   }

   public void setBackgroundImg(BufferedImage background) {
      this.backgroundImg = background;
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (backgroundImg != null) {
         g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, this);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return prefSize;
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyBorder extends AbstractBorder {
   private BufferedImage borderImg;
   private Insets insets;

   public MyBorder(BufferedImage borderImg, Insets insets) {
      this.borderImg = borderImg;
      this.insets = insets;
   }

   @Override
   public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width,
         int height) {
      g.drawImage(borderImg, 0, 0, c);
   }

   @Override
   public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
      return insets;
   }
}
```

Which would look like so:

[image]